# How to create a lattice and link all objects to it procedurally?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I've been trying to do that but have got some problems:

1. I was not able to retrieve the reference to a recently created object with `bpy.ops.object.add()`.
   I had to use `bpy.ops.lattice.select_all()`, but that sounds inelegant.
2. While I was able to create a lattice for each object with `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='LATTICE')`, I was not able to link it - mostly because the command to link a lattice modifier to the lattice object won't show on the info window. (Also, this needs the object to be selected...)

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way is to not use operators:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

lattice = bpy.data.lattices.new("Lattice")
lattice_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Lattice", lattice)
lattice_ob.scale = (5, 5, 5)

for ob in scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        mod = ob.modifiers.new("Lattice", 'LATTICE')
        mod.object = lattice_ob

scene.objects.link(lattice_ob)
scene.update()
```

The `.new()` methods return object references to be used for subsequent method calls and property assignments in contrast to operators, which run isolated and [only return a status](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.ops.html) (e.g. `{'FINISHED'}`). Some methods also take objects (the second parameter of `objects.new()`), whereas operators don't support objects/pointers, but only references by name (StringProperty).

**//update:** For Blender 2.8 and above, I believe you would do it like this:

```
import bpy

collection = bpy.context.collection

lattice = bpy.data.lattices.new("Lattice")
lattice_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Lattice", lattice)
lattice_ob.scale = (5, 5, 5)

for ob in collection.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        mod = ob.modifiers.new("Lattice", 'LATTICE')
        mod.object = lattice_ob

collection.objects.link(lattice_ob)
```

Comment: insightful, thank you. Hopefully knowing that option will make it easier next time. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work on 2.90 .... :((
`AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'`
Can it be updated?

Comment: Added a possible solution for Blender 2.8+, but I don't know whether this is the canonical way to go about it. At least it seems like no `update()` call is needed anymore. Maybe `object_data_add()` from `bpy_extras.object_utils` would be better and includes a layer update.

Comment: `bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(lattice_ob)` add that line after setting the scale.